# How can I make the following table quickly?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, syntax

Consider a table

```
Tabb = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}];
```

I want to make the following table:

```
Tabb1=Flatten[Table[{Tabb[[i]][[1]],j,Tabb[[i]][[2]]},{i,1,Length[Tabb],1},{j,1,3,1}],{1,2}];
```

Is there a more elegant or faster way of making `Tabb1`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tabb has the structure:

```
{{a[1, 1], a[1, 2]}, {a[2, 1], a[2, 2]}, {a[3, 1], a[3, 2]}}
```

Now you want to introduce 1 in sublist 1. This can be done with "Riffle":

```
Riffle[{a[1, 1], a[1, 2]}, 1]

{a[1, 1], 1, a[1, 2]}
```

Then you want introduce 2 in sublist 2 and 3 in sublist 3. This is a job for "Outer:"

```
Flatten[Outer[Riffle[#1, #2] &, Tabb, {1, 2, 3}, 1], 1] ;
```

The result of this a list with depth 3, but you want a result of depth 2. We therefore need and additional "Flatten":

```
Flatten[Outer[Riffle[#1, #2] &, Tabb, {1, 2, 3}, 1], 1]

{{a[1, 1], 1, a[1, 2]}, {a[1, 1], 2, a[1, 2]}, {a[1, 1], 3, 
  a[1, 2]}, {a[2, 1], 1, a[2, 2]}, {a[2, 1], 2, a[2, 2]}, {a[2, 1], 3,
   a[2, 2]}, {a[3, 1], 1, a[3, 2]}, {a[3, 1], 2, a[3, 2]}, {a[3, 1], 
  3, a[3, 2]}}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
Tabb = Array[a, {3, 2}];
```

John Taylor (original)

```
t1 = RepeatedTiming[
   Tabb1 = Flatten[
      Table[{Tabb[[i]][[1]], j, Tabb[[i]][[2]]}, {i, 1, Length[Tabb], 1}, {j, 
        1, 3, 1}], {1, 2}];][[1]]

(* 0.0000139952 *)
```

Bob Hanlon

```
t2 = RepeatedTiming[
   Tabb2 = Flatten[Thread[{#[[1]], Range[3], #[[2]]}] & /@ Tabb, 1];][[1]]

(* 9.29298*10^-6 *)
```

Roman

```
t3 = RepeatedTiming[
   Tabb3 = Join @@ Outer[{#1[[1]], #2, #1[[2]]} &, Tabb, Range[3], 1];][[1]]

(* 0.0000116235 *)
```

Daniel Huber

```
t4 = RepeatedTiming[
   Tabb4 = Flatten[Outer[Riffle[#1, #2] &, Tabb, {1, 2, 3}, 1], 1];][[1]]

(* 7.44106*10^-6 *)
```

**EDIT:**

kglr

```
t5 = RepeatedTiming[Tabb5 = Riffle @@@ Tuples[{Tabb, Range[3]}];][[1]]

(* 7.01392*10^-6 *)
```

The methods provide equivalent results

```
Tabb1 === Tabb2 === Tabb3 === Tabb4 === Tabb5

(* True *)
```

kglr's is now the most efficient

```
{t1, t2, t3, t4, t5}/t5

(* {2.23145, 1.29783, 1.5505, 1.06513, 1.} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Tabb1 == Join @@ Outer[{#1[[1]], #2, #1[[2]]} &, Tabb, Range[3], 1]
(*    True    *)
```

Comment: I was just going to amend `Tabb1 == Join @@ Outer[Riffle, Tabb, Range[3], 1]` but @DanielHuber beat me to it.

Answer (score 4):

```
Riffle @@@ Tuples[{Tabb, Range[3]}]
```

[image]

Also

```
Map[Splice@Thread[{First@#, Range@3, Last@#}] &] @ Tabb 

Tabb1 == % == %%
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
Partition[
  Riffle[Flatten[ConstantArray[Tabb, 3], {{2, 1, 3}}], Range@3, {2, -2, 3}], 3]
```

:

```
Tabb = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10000, 2}];
r1 = Map[Splice@Thread[{First@#, Range@3, Last@#}] &]@Tabb; // RepeatedTiming
r2 = Riffle @@@ Tuples[{Tabb, Range[3]}]; // RepeatedTiming
r3 = Partition[Riffle[Flatten[
       ConstantArray[Tabb, 3], {{2, 1, 3}}], Range@3, {2, -2, 3}], 3]; // RepeatedTiming
r1 === r2 === r3
```

> ```
> {0.0192981, Null}
> {0.0220029, Null}
> {0.00404638, Null}
> True
> ```